# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Hello everyone and thanks in advance,
I write you on the forum to ask for your help.
I have a problem on a program to invert an image with PIL.
Voici le code complet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import random as r
from math import *



def ouvrir(nomimage):
    img=Image.open(nomimage)  
    return img

def affiche(img):
    img.show()


def imc2img(imc,n):
    img=Image.new("F",imc.size) 
    pixc=imc.load() 
    pixg=img.load()
    width = imc.size[0] 
    height=imc.size[1]
    for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            pixg[i,j]=pixc[i,j][n]
    return img

def imc2r(ims):
    imr=imc2img(ims,1)
    return imr

def inverse_image(ims):
    img=Image.new("L",ims.size)
    pixc=ims.load()
    pixg=img.load()
    width=ims.size[0]
    height=ims.size[1]
    for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            imi=pixg[i,j]=pixc[(255-i),(255-j)]
    return imi
```

Find the problem and try to solve this?

```
  def inverse_image(ims):
    img=Image.new("L",ims.size)
    pixc=ims.load()
    pixg=img.load()
    width=ims.size[0]
    height=ims.size[1]
    for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            imi=pixg[i,j]=255-pixc[i,j]
    return imi
```

the error code was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>

    imi=inverse_image(ims)
  File "C:\Users\Geoffray\Desktop\TP_note\code.py", line 43, in inverse_image

    imi=pixg[i,j]=255-pixc[i,j]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Thanks You!
I hope that my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: You should include the full traceback Python gives you. Despite that, the error is at the only place `-` is used: `255-pixc[i,j]`. `pixc[i, j]` is a tuple.

Comment: That's what I thought.Do you have a idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: pixc[i,j] is a tuple, not an integer. It's not clear how to solve this problem because it's not clear what you're expecting pixc[i,j] to be

Comment: What do you expect subtracting a tuple from 255 to do?

Comment: it's a task for the university and my professor told us that to invert the image, it was the equation to be

Comment: Each pixel has multiple color channels. You're likely encountering [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#Numeric_representations). Each color channel within pixc[i,j] must be subtracted from 255 individually.

Comment: i have try " imi=pixg[i,j]=pixc[255-i,255-j]"

Comment: i have solved this problem, the picture was in color, but it must it grey. Thanks you for your help!